# Exact Keyword search phrases

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

The search engine I'm using is a MySQL/PHP search engine.

I have been searching the forums for some time to try to get a solution for this problem.

If I have keywords for 3 separate images labeled:

- #1 pure black
- #2 pure white
- #3 pure green

If I type "pure white" in the search box all 3 images come up because they all share the word "pure".

Is there a workaround or code I can add to only match exact search phrases when using multiple search keywords?

This is the code:

```
<?php
  //get data
  $button = $_GET['submit'];
  $search = $_GET['search'];

  $s = $_GET['s'];
  if (!$s)
    $s = 0;

  $e = 10; 

  $next = $s + $e;
  $prev = $s - $e;

  if (strlen($search) <= 2)
    echo "Must be greater then 3 chars";
  else {
    echo "<br /><table><tr><td><img src='juzzy.jpg' /></td><td><form action='search.php' method='GET'><input type='text' onclick=value='' size='50' name='search' value='$search'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search'></form></td></tr></table>";

  //connect to database
  mysql_connect("","","");
  mysql_select_db("");

  //explode out search term
  $search_exploded = explode(" ",$search);

  foreach($search_exploded as $search_each) {
    //construct query
    $x++;
    if ($x == 1)
      $construct .= "keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    else
      $construct .= " OR keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";    
    }

    //echo outconstruct
    $constructx = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE $construct";

    $construct = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE $construct ORDER BY keywords LIMIT $s,$e ";
    $run = mysql_query($constructx);

    $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
    $run_two = mysql_query("$construct");

    if ($foundnum == 0)
      echo "No results found for <b>$search</b>";
    else {
      echo "<table bgcolor='#0000FF' width='100%' height='1px'><br /></table><table bgcolor='#f0f7f9' width='100%' height='10px'><tr><td><div align='right'>Showing 1-10 of <b>$foundnum</b> results found for <b>$search.</b></div></td></tr></table><p>";

   while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_two)) {
    //get data
    $title = $runrows['title'];
    $desc = $runrows['description'];
    $url = $runrows['url'];

    echo "<table width='300px'>
    <h4><a href='http://$url'><b>$title</b></a><br />
    $desc<br>
    <font color='00CC00'>$url</font></table></h4>";
   }
?>

<table width='100%'>
<tr>
<td>
<div align="center">

<?php
if (!$s<=0)
 echo "<a href='search.php?search=$search&s=$prev'>Prev</a>";

$i =1; 
for ($x=0;$x<$foundnum;$x=$x+$e) {    
 echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&s=$x'>$i</a> ";    
 $i++;    
}

if ($s<$foundnum-$e)
  echo "<a href='search.php?search=$search&s=$next'>Next</a>";
}
}  


?>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't explode your search string.  This will force it to use the full search string as a search, rather than any one of the pieces.

Or, you could change your operator OR in your construct to AND, and that way it would require all the words to appear, regardless of order, however.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use fuzzy `LIKE %%` queries, query by `keywords = '$search'`.

Comment: You'll still have to skip the explode portion if you do this, or you'll never get a match.

Comment: perfect works. one more thing. if i change the order to white pure how can i get the image 2 with pure white come up too

Comment: That's a bit too vague to answer in one comment. Exact text matching is easy. Exact part matching is easy too. Anything beyond that deserves much more consideration. Search for "fulltext search engine" or open a specific question with more details of what should and shouldn't match.